# Does the French language have an "oy" sound?

Tags: prononciation

So "oi" in French is pronounced as *wah* phonetically. But does French have the "oy" sound like other Romance languages do? But that I mean "oy" as in "boy" or "toy" or "hoy"(in Spanish).

This is a diphthong with a mid back rounded starting point [ɔ ~ o] and a high front offglide [ɪ ~ i j].

Comment: Not a diphthong but two nuclei in a row: égoïste

Comment: You’d think it would – [oj] would be the expected pronunciation of _oille_, which seems like a perfectly reasonable sequence. But I can’t seem to locate any words that contain it at all. Given that the most obvious ancestor of such a sequence, Romance _*olia_, generally becomes _euille_ [œj], it’s quite possible there aren’t any.

Comment: Sursilvan Romansh is also considered to lack the /oj ~ ɔj/ diphthong.

Comment: Are you asking about Modern Parisian French, and limiting the inquiry to etymologically Romance words?

Comment: A French word contains the sequence *oille*, precisely the word *[oille](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oille)* from the Spanish *olla* and pronounced /ɔj/ but it is not used anymore.

Comment: You might want to update the question with some linguistic terminology, like “diphthong with a mid back rounded starting point [ɔ ~ o] and a high front offglide [ɪ ~ i j]” since that generalizes away from being the exact same as the English sound towards a sound LIKE the English one. In phonology, we should always consider speech sounds in the context of their systems.

Comment: Interestingly, the two main predecessors of French on the territory did have that sound. Occitan dialects (langue d'oc) have a lot of it, spelled "òi". *Còire*: to cook. As for langue d'oïl, I'm not a specialist but since its very name (which means "oui") contains that sound, chances are other words in its various dialects do as well.

Comment: @guillaume31 oïl was two syllables, which you can see in the its outcomes in various languages, for example French /o.'i/ > /u.'i/ > /'wi/ or Walloon/o.'i/ > /ɔ.'ji/ where stress remains on /i/ and the undressed /o/ evolves as expected

Comment: @Eauquidort possible. But the Q is about a general sound, not syllables or stress.

Comment: @guillaume31 Yes, anf that sound is a diphthong with a peak on the first element, which oïl might have in its modern lay pronunciation, but not in any of its historical realisations

Comment: What is "Modern Parisian French"?

Answer (score 14):

There are several words of foreign origin used in French that contain the /ɔj/ diphtong, including ***barzoï, boy-scout, boycotter, cow-boy, foil, goy, joystick, spoiler**,* and ***monoï***.

In addition, there is at least one word (a very French one because it names the French language family spoken in the Middle Ages) that contains this "oy" diphtong, it's the word *oïl* found in *[**langue d'oïl**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langues_d%27o%C3%AFl)*

[**Listen to it pronounced  here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voj5JqyJfi4&t=475s)

Comment: _Langue d’oïl_, of course! I feel rather silly now for not thinking of that…

Comment: So barzoï would be pronounced "bar-zoy" and not "barz-wah"? I take it if the i has an umlaut on it that is what makes the difference, no?

Comment: Yes, *barzoï* rhymes with *Tolstoï*.

Comment: @MrX, the diacritic, as far as I know, is called a diaeresis.

Comment: "Umlaut" is the sound change the two dots on a vowel often represent, but I believe the two diacritics evolved to look the same independently. This one was used to indicate where two vowels are nuclei to separate syllables, instead of representing a diphthong (precisely for stuff like distinguishing "oy" versus "wah" pronounciations).

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM Correct. We can also call this diacritic *trema* encompassing both *umlaut* and *diaeresis*.

Comment: d'oïl has two syllables /do i/ and does not have the diphthong /oj/.

Comment: @fdb No, neither /o.i/ nor /oj/ but /ɔj/. You would even risk not being understood if you pronounce it with two syllables, *la langue d'eau-île??*

Comment: @fdb Maybe are you referring to the medieval pronunciation? *Hoc ille* surely started as two syllables.

Comment: Three syllables, even.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the answer of @jlliagre, here is a tool from the French Wiktionary, with all the words that contains /ɔj/ in their pronunciations: [Anagrimes](https://anagrimes.toolforge.org/chercher_prononciation.php?place=partout&rime=%C9%94j&langue=fr&type=&liste=table&flex=oui&loc=oui&gent=oui#liste). This tool gives 1430 words (lemmas, but also declensions and demonyms).

Comment: [_Ayoye_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ayoye#fr-interj) !